# Getting error message on Minecraft launcher

Tags: minecraft-java-edition-server

I'm getting this: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Using incremental CMS is deprecated and will likely be removed in a future release
Error: Could not find or load main class net.minecraft.client.main.Main
I have an upgraded java and it was working earlier. I have been on Mojang website, no problems and have set security question-   minecraft doesn't load.
I can't get past this launcher message

Comment: It's not a duplicate. There is a new issue that just came up today. There is already a bug report at https://bugs.mojang.com/projects/MC/issues/MC-121292  I'm having the same issue.

Comment: Based on what we have, that's the best we can do.  We'd need way more than that to do anything else.

Comment: This question wasn't a duplicate.

Comment: This was not a duplicate, it was a new issue and is not resolved.

Answer (score -1):

There seems to be a new bug that started affecting a lot of people today:

https://bugs.mojang.com/projects/MC/issues/MC-121292

Comment: Maybe someone could explain why my answer, which pointed to the bug report for the problem, was modded down.

Comment: deltaray, I now play Minecraft offline only on an older launcher. It's a little lonely but I have my horses. I wish Notch was back